# add textbox before another textbox with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have five textboxs in HTML. I want to add another textbox before textbox3 with javascript. How can I do it?

```
<input type="text" id="43" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" id="85" name="textbox2">
<input type="text" id="10" name="textbox3">
<input type="text" id="25" name="textbox4">
<input type="text" id="99" name="textbox5">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show effort and code. This is a duplicate of many questions - try to find one before asking

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use jquery to do this :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="43" name="textbox1">
      <input type="text" id="85" name="textbox2">
      <input type="text" id="10" name="textbox3">
      <input type="text" id="25" name="textbox4">
      <input type="text" id="99" name="textbox5">
      
      <script>
        //Event handler on deutsch click
        $( '<input type="text" id="99" name="textbox31">' ).insertAfter( "[name=textbox3]" );
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He want in javascript

Comment: If the question isn't tagged with jQuery assume it is not acceptable - note I didn't downvote,

Comment: THANKS THANKS THANKS

Answer (score 0):

```js
var textbox3 = document.getElementsByName("textbox3")[0];
var newTextbox = document.createElement("input");
newTextbox.setAttribute("type", "text");
var parent = textbox3.parentElement;
    
parent.insertBefore(newTextbox, textbox3);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="43" name="textbox1" value="1">
<input type="text" id="85" name="textbox2" value="2">
<input type="text" id="10" name="textbox3" value="3">
<input type="text" id="25" name="textbox4" value="4">
<input type="text" id="99" name="textbox5" value="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select element with `document.getElementById()` with parameter `"10"` to match element having `id` `"10"`; use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` with first parameter set to `"afterend"` and second parameter set to `html` string of `<input>` element

```html
<input type="text" id="43" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" id="85" name="textbox2">
<input type="text" id="10" name="textbox3">
<input type="text" id="25" name="textbox4">
<input type="text" id="99" name="textbox5">
<script>
  document.getElementById("10")
  .insertAdjacentHTML("afterend"
  , "<input type=text id=123 name=textbox3-5 value=3.5>");
</script>
```

Comment: THANKS THANKS THANKS

Comment: guest271314 you win xD I didn't even know about insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

using `insertBefore`

```js
var new_text = document.createElement("input");
/* set attributes as you want */
//new_text.type = "text";
//new_text.id= "60";
//new_text.name="textbox3-2";
new_text.value="4th text input";
document.getElementsByName("textbox3")[0].parentNode.insertBefore(new_text, document.getElementsByName("textbox3")[0]);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="43" name="textbox1"/>
<input type="text" id="85" name="textbox2"/>
<input type="text" id="10" name="textbox3"/>
<input type="text" id="25" name="textbox4"/>
<input type="text" id="99" name="textbox5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
/* Adds Element AFTER NeighborElement */
Element.prototype.appendAfter = function (element) {
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);
}, false;

/* Typical Creation and Setup A New Orphaned Element Object */


  var NewElement = document.createElement("INPUT");
    NewElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
    NewElement.setAttribute("value", "");

/*  Add NewElement BEFORE -OR- AFTER Using the Aforementioned Prototypes */
NewElement.appendAfter(document.getElementById('10'));
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/6cyth9k6/

Comment: THANKS THANKS THANKS